# Перевод всплывающих сообщений при попытке изменить чью-то репутацию новичком

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Поскольку я совсем недавно вернулся в сообщество, и у меня не хватает репутации для голосования, заметил "недоперевод" при попытке проголосовать:

[image: При попытке поставить +]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @fori1ton, оказывается этот вопрос уже был задан на английском языке. Я искал, задаваля ли он ранее именно на русском. Поэтому не заметил. Почему допускаются вопросы на английском в русской версии stackoverflow?

Comment: Иногда сообщения об ошибках ru.SO постят не сюда, а на Meta Stack Exchange - общий мета-сайт всей сети. Такие сообщения переносятся сюда модераторами Meta SE. Перевод у таких сообщений отсутствует так как их пишут англоязычные пользователи, которые не могут их перевести на русский. Насчёт допустимости перевода таких вопросов на русский другими участниками сообщества - отдельный вопрос, тут стоит поинтересоваться мнением администрации, например, @Nicolas Chabanovsky.

Comment: @fori1ton, спасибо за ответ. Я, конечно, знаю, что общий мета-сайт был придуман не просто так. Думал, что там обсуждают работу всей сети в общем, но, оказывается, там обсуждают всё подряд. Я вот не пойму, зачем нужен общий мета-сайт, если у каждого проекта из сети есть свой мета-сайт?

Comment: Основная цель общего мета-сайта - обсуждение предложений и багов, затрагивающих все сообщества. Сообщения, касающиеся одного конкретного сообщества должны обсуждаться исключительно на мета-сайте этого сообщества. Если такое сообщение было опубликовано на общем мета-сайте - его переносял в локальный.

Comment: @fori1ton, теперь всё ясно. Спасибо.